# Error on SQL syntax when inserting new event

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, syntax-error

I'm getting this error when trying to add a new event on my page. Can anyone help? I've tried everything and am a beginner. Thanks in advance!

'SQL Syntax error: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 2'

```
<?php
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) { 
require_once("db.php");
$results = ""; 
$venue = "";  
$eventname = ""; 
$startdate = ""; 
$starttime ="";  
$enddate = ""; 
$endtime = ""; 


$query = "SELECT DISTINCT venue
      FROM event
      ORDER BY venue";

$results = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " .     mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
$venue .= "<option>{$row['venue']}</option>";
}

$eventname .= "<option>{$row["event_name"]} </option>";
 $startdate .= "<option>{$row["begin_date"]}
</option>";


$enddate .= "<option>{$row["end_date"]}
</option>";


mysqli_free_result($results);
mysqli_close($con);}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Adding a New Event</title>
<link href="ODC.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<img class="homepageback" width="150" height="150" src= "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/85/86/3b/85863b5dcd05835a7d12db5d88115b70.jpg"/>


<div class="container">

  <center><img class="displayed" width="150" height="150" src= "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/816431933081014272/kXQVW1xX.jpg"/></center>
  <h3>Add a New Event</h3>
  <form method="post" action="enter-event-insert.php">

    <div><label for="event_name">Event Name: </label><input name="event_name"></div>

    <div><label for="venue []">Event Venue: </label><select multiple name="venue">
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
<?php
foreach ($_POST['venue'] as $names)
{
print "Your Venue is Selected $names<br/>";
}

?>
</select>
</div>

<div><label for="begin_date">Start Date And Time: </label><input     type="datetime-local" name="begin_date"></div>

<div><label for="end_date">End Date And Time: </label><input type="datetime-local" name="end_date"></div>

    <div><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit"></div>

  </form>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: run the query in your phpmyadmin and verify you get results

Comment: There is no `INSERT` query in here...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced an issue like this before where I was unable to insert values into a database, however, the statement when ran in phpmyadmin worked fine. So first, I'd highly recommend you first execute the statement in phpmyadmin, make sure it's been typed out correctly. Next, if the statement executed fine but the code still doesn't work, try using backticks (``) in your fields to see if that'll help (fixed my issue with the values). For future reference, you can also use websites like [this MySQL syntax checker](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) in order to verify that your syntax is correct (which I have already checked for you, and it is).

Comment: This is not bad advice, but it's not an *answer*.

Comment: I was going to comment on the main thread and wanted to share the advice, but I don't meet the requirements as of yet, so answering was the only way I knew how to tell him some tips to fix it.

Comment: The easiest way to work your way up to that point is to ask a few well-formed questions that describe problems you need help with. An opportunity to share and learn.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.